# Getting Foreman to run sidekiq and mailcatcher

Tags: sidekiq, foreman, mailcatcher

When I try running foreman I get this message:

`$ foreman start
00:29:24 worker.1      | started with pid 44135
00:29:24 mailcatcher.1 | started with pid 44136
00:29:24 worker.1      | /usr/local/foreman/bin/foreman-runner: line 41: exec: sidekiq: not found
00:29:24 mailcatcher.1 | /usr/local/foreman/bin/foreman-runner: line 41: exec: mailcatcher: not found
00:29:24 mailcatcher.1 | exited with code 127
00:29:24 system        | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
00:29:24 worker.1      | exited with code 127`

I've tried reinstalling the foreman gem but nothing changes. I can't seem to find out what the error is on google or why sidekiq and mailcatcher are not found. The gems are bothe bundled and installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis needed to be turned on by typing `redis-server` in the terminal